# confusing actions in Struts2 submit button

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to update the existing code of other developer. I am facing the problem of confusing actions.

Existing :

```
<s:form name="f2" action="delFood.action">

<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="button" onClick="javascript:get_check_value()"/>
```

**My Code to Update:**

```
<input type="file" class="button" id="foodItemFile" name="foodItemFile" value="Browse ..."/>    
<input type="submit" class="button" value="AddFood" onClick="callAddFood();"/>
```

**My Javascript:**
In my script, I try to submit my action by following code.

```
document.f2.action = "AddFoodAction.action";
document.f2.submit();
```

It seems like when I click [AddFood] button, it always call the [delFood.action].

For adding food, I need to check something with javascripts before calling the [AddFoodAction.action] action.

Due to limitations, I can't change the existing code. I can only add new codes to the existing one.

So, ***Any way to call [AddFoodAction.action] from javascripts without confusing with other actions of the same form ?***

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolve it by doing like that.

1) There will no direct action in form tag.

```
<s:form name="f2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2) for delete part,

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="button" onClick="javascript:get_check_value()"/>
```

call the delete action from the javascript, not directly from form.

```
document.f2.action = "delFood.action";
```

3) for add part, like delete part. check necessary things in java scripts and call the add action. It works well.

Another Solution:

There maybe common action directly called from Form. For this approach, just name your button and give value and map those value from action class. And differentiate multiple methods by using those value from one action. I read this article at [coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/431831/Struts/Struts-distinguish-multiple-submit-button)  and [javaSample](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=577). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a javascript problem here. Make sure the code

```
document.f2.action = "AddFoodAction.action";
document.f2.submit();
```

is executing. Maybe `document.f2` is not resolving correctly (maybe more than one form with this name?).

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHYpH/9/) shows that it should work. It changes the action of a form inside a `onclick` handler on a `<input type="submit">`.

And just a reccomendation, don't do `document.f2.submit();`. It's an `<input type="submit">` so it will submit the form automatically when `onclick` ends.

Comment: thanks for the tip. yah I now don't use document.f2.submit() anymore because the button itself is `<input type="submit">`